# How do you animate the array using Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I have made conways game of life but dont know how to animate the cellular automata. I want to see them moving step by step in a single window.

i feel as though its something simple, but cant quite figure out what. I'd prefer it if things were kept to matplotlib. The rule function adds/deletes values on the array in accordance with the game of life by the way.

cheers.

````
***import numpy
import time
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
dimension=100
a=numpy.zeros((dimension, dimension))
number_of_automata=200
iterations=1000
count=0
def main():
    global its
    its=0
    while its!=iterations:
        rule()
        print_function()
def print_function():
    plt.imshow(a, interpolation='none')
    plt.show()
generate_random_points()
main()
```***
````

Comment: please refere this https://sites.google.com/site/igorlugoolmos/projects/python/cellular-automata